# DNScrypt proxy and Ubuntu 16.04 - can't run it on startup

Tags: networking, dnscrypt-proxy

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed `dnscrypt-proxy` from repository.
Then I have just edited the `/etc/default/dnscrypt-proxy` file changing the `DNSCRYPT_PROXY_RESOLVER_NAME=""` line with  `DNSCRYPT_PROXY_RESOLVER_NAME=cisco`.
After that I have just ran the following commands:

```
sudo service dnscrypt-proxy stop
sudo service dnscrypt-proxy start
```

and everything was working fine.

The problem is that after reboot my internet connection does not work and I have to run this again:

```
sudo service dnscrypt-proxy stop
sudo service dnscrypt-proxy start
```

to make it work.
What I need is a way to make `dnscrypt-proxy` starts automatically at startup like it used to work before upgrading to 16.04.

I tried to put those commands in `/etc/rc.local` file but sometimes it did not work.
Also I created a bash script with those commands and I made it run at startup, but still no luck.

Could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Note that cisco keeps logs of your connections, you may wanna try another one from the list.

Answer (score 0):

The following things helped me:

- run `sudo systemctl edit --full dnscrypt-proxy.service`
- replace

  ```
  After=network.target iptables.service firewalld.service
  ```

  to

  ```
  After=network.target
  Before=nss-lookup.target
  ```
- run `sudo systemctl edit --full dnscrypt-proxy.socket`
- delete `After=network.target`

Also **/etc/systemd/system/dnscrypt-proxy.service** and **/etc/systemd/system/dnscrypt-proxy.socket** can be replaced with [their latest versions](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy).